# How can I read a word after having read a numeral from the Lua console?

Tags: input, lua

I tried to write some simple code for mathematical equations, reading console input. Here's my minimal executable example:

```
print("Please enter a number")
local number = io.read("*n")
print("You entered the number: " .. number)
print("Please enter 'yes'")
local word = io.read("*l")
if word == "yes" then
  print("Thank you!")
else
  print(":(")
end
```

I entered `1`, pressed return, then entered `yes` and pressed return, but I always get the following output in the Lua console:

```
 Please enter a number
 >> 1
 You entered the number: 1
 Please enter 'yes'
 :(
```

I don't understand why I cannot even enter `yes`. The program just terminates.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Reading a number is a bit counter-intuitive in Lua (it reads a number without LF after that number).  Replace all `io.read("*n")` with `io.read("*n", "*l")` to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Egor `io.read("*n")` will read a numeral without the linefeed after that number.

So if you enter `1` and read that with `io.read("*n")`, you will actually leave an empty line in the input stream.

Once you read a new line with `io.read("*l")` Lua will read that empty line from the stream. Therefor it does not wait for your input, but evaluates the content of `word` immediately.

As `word` is an empty string `word == "yes"` is `false`.

You can fix that by using `io.read("*n", "*l")` for reading the numeral and the following emtpy line. That way the input stream is empty when you call io.read("*l") next and Lua will wait for you to enter your word.

You can do run this code:

```
print("Enter 1")
local number, newLine = io.read("*n", "*L")
print(number == 1)
print(newLine == "\n")
```

To see that your number is indeed followed by a `"\n"`